# How to change admin detail view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a question about Django-Admin Detail View. I have some items in admin Django, and when I click on them, it will show up detail of that specific item. Every item has some status, which could be changed by the user.

And now I am getting to the problem... I want to show only relevant fields, buttons, etc. which will depend on item status or type of person. Which part of code will I put in admin.py under the specific class to make it work?

I tried something like this for superuser but it will not work. Can you please show me how to display only some fields based on user status or item status(field name: Status ... in models)

```
class JournalEntriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager', 'EngagementIncharge')
    list_filter = ('published', 'EngagementCode')
    search_fields = ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager', 'EngagementIncharge')

    def show_relevant(self, obj):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets = (
                    (None, {  # label 1: None
                        'fields': ( # dictionary
                            ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager'),

                        )
                    }),
                    ('More details', { # under label 2 : More details
                        'classes': ('collapse',),  # css-class : minimized
                        'fields': (
                            ('published'),
                        )
                    })
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `get_fieldsets` is what you're looking for

```py
class JournalEntriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager', 'EngagementIncharge')
    list_filter = ('published', 'EngagementCode')
    search_fields = ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager', 'EngagementIncharge')

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets = (
                    (None, {  # label 1: None
                        'fields': ( # dictionary
                            ('EngagementCode', 'EngagementManager'),
                        )
                    }),
                    ('More details', { # under label 2 : More details
                        'classes': ('collapse',),  # css-class : minimized
                        'fields': (
                            ('published'),
                        )
                    })
                )
        else:
            fieldsets = super().get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        return fieldsets
```

Note you will have to return either fieldsets or an empty tuple for no fieldsets, so you will need to decide what to return if the user is not a superuser. I have just called `super` in the else statement for now.

You can also control what fields appear on a add/change page with `get_fields`.

Also if you wanted to control what actions, filters and columns appear on the list view page depending on the user you can use `get_actions`, `get_list_filter` and `get_list_display` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for update but right now I am getting:  'NoneType' object is not iterable, can you please help me to fix it? @mikeylockwood

Comment: @webmourek sorry missed the return statement. It needs to return the fieldsets. Note you will always need to return fieldsets or an empty tuple for no fieldsets. So you will need to decide what to return if the user is not a superuser. I have just called super in that case for now

Comment: thanks a lot. I have one more think, how can I do it based on some value ? lets say, i want to show something if the EngagementManager will have value "XY".

Comment: Yeah I know, I already figure it out with the super and not super user :)

Comment: @webmourek `if obj and obj.EngagementManager == 'XY':`. You will always need to check `if obj` before checking against fields on the object because this will run on adding as well as changing. If adding objects, obj will be `None` so `obj.EngagementManager` would throw an error.

Comment: Thank you so much !